# How to extract a function where I can pass functions as parameters for these chained lambdas in Java 8?

Tags: java, lambda, apache-kafka-streams, method-chaining

I have a code pattern in a piece of code using Kafka Streams that keeps repeating, I do a map, then group by key and then reduce. It looks like this:

```
KTable<ProjectKey, EventConfigurationIdsWithDeletedState> eventConfigurationsByProjectTable = eventConfigurationStream
        .map((key, value) -> {
            Map<String, Boolean> eventConfigurationUpdates = new HashMap<>();
            eventConfigurationUpdates.put(key.getEventConfigurationId(), value != null);
            ProjectKey projectKey = ProjectKey.newBuilder().setId(key.getProjectId()).build();
            EventConfigurationIdsWithDeletedState eventConfigurationIdsWithDeletedState = EventConfigurationIdsWithDeletedState.newBuilder().setEventConfigurations(eventConfigurationUpdates).build();
            return KeyValue.pair(projectKey, eventConfigurationIdsWithDeletedState);
        })
        .groupByKey()
        .reduce((aggValue, newValue) -> {
            Map<String, Boolean> newEventConfigurations = newValue.getEventConfigurations();
            Map<String, Boolean> aggEventConfigurations = aggValue.getEventConfigurations();
            Map.Entry<String, Boolean> newEntry = newEventConfigurations.entrySet().iterator().next();
            if (newEntry.getValue())
                aggEventConfigurations.putAll(newEventConfigurations);
            else
                aggEventConfigurations.remove(newEntry.getKey());
            if (aggEventConfigurations.size() == 0)
                return null;
            return aggValue;
        });
```

(with eventConfigurationStream being of type `KStream<EventConfigurationKey, EventConfiguration>`)

Another example that follows this pattern. Note there's a filter here too but that isn't always the case:

```
KTable<ProjectKey, NotificationSettingsTransition> globalNotificationSettingsPerProjectTable = notificationSettingTable.toStream()
        .filter((key, value) -> {
            return key.getEventConfigurationId() == null;
        })
        .map((key, value) -> {
            ProjectKey projectKey = ProjectKey.newBuilder().setId(key.getProjectId()).build();
            Map<String, NotificationSetting> notificationSettingsMap = new HashMap<>();
            notificationSettingsMap.put(getAsCompoundKeyString(key), value);
            NotificationSettingsTransition notificationSettingTransition = NotificationSettingsTransition
                    .newBuilder()
                    .setNotificationSettingCompoundKeyLastUpdate(getAsCompoundKey(key))
                    .setNotificationSettingLastUpdate(value)
                    .setEventConfigurationIds(new ArrayList<>())
                    .setNotificationSettingsMap(notificationSettingsMap)
                    .build();

            return KeyValue.pair(projectKey, notificationSettingTransition);
        })
        .groupByKey()
        .reduce((aggValue, newValue) -> {
            Map<String, NotificationSetting> notificationSettingMap = aggValue.getNotificationSettingsMap();
            String compoundKeyAsString = getAsString(newValue.getNotificationSettingCompoundKeyLastUpdate());
            if (newValue.getNotificationSettingLastUpdate() != null)
                notificationSettingMap.put(compoundKeyAsString, newValue.getNotificationSettingLastUpdate());
            else
                notificationSettingMap.remove(compoundKeyAsString);
            aggValue.setNotificationSettingCompoundKeyLastUpdate(newValue.getNotificationSettingCompoundKeyLastUpdate());
            aggValue.setNotificationSettingLastUpdate(newValue.getNotificationSettingLastUpdate());
            aggValue.setNotificationSettingsMap(notificationSettingMap);
            return aggValue;
        });
```

(with notificationSettingsTable being of type `KTable<NotificationSettingKey, NotificationSetting> notificationSettingTable` but immediately being transformed into a KStream as well.)

How could I extract this into a function where I pass a function for the map code and for the reduce code but do not have to repeat the pattern of `.map().groupByKey().reduce()`? While respecting that the return types are different and depend on the code in the map function and should remain typed. Ideally in Java 8 but higher versions are potentially possible. I think I have a good idea of how to do it when the inner types of the `KeyValuePair` within the map code wouldn't change, but not sure how to do it now.

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question: are you asking if you can write a method which runs `map(A).gBK().reduce(B)`? If so, I'm not convinced that would give you any substantial benefit: the bulk of that code is in the `A` and `B` code blocks, and you'd still need to keep that.

Comment: @AndyTurner yeah that's it, because I am repeating that pattern 3 or 4 times now, with potentially more instances coming up. If it will never look as readable as just typing it out like this then I could accept that but I prefer not to repeat myself. Indeed the code within the blocks is always custom per case, though it might follow a pattern too.

Comment: You better ask this question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parameterise your function to accept two generic functions, where the types will be inferred (or set explicitely if not possible) when the function is called.

For the input to `map`, you want a `BiFunction<K, V, T>`, and for `reduce` you want a `BiFunction<U, U, U>`, where:

- `K` is the type of `key` in `map`'s function.
- `V` is the type of `value` in `map`'s function.
- `T` is the return type of `map`'s function.
- `U` is the type of the aggregator, values and return type of `reduce`'s function.

Looking at [`KStream`](https://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html) and [`KGroupedStream`](https://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KGroupedStream.html), you can get more detailed type information to constrain the functions further.

This would make your custom function something like this:

```
<K, V, T, U> U mapGroupReduce(final KStream<K, V> stream, final BiFunction<K, V, T> mapper, final BiFunction<U, U, U> reducer) {
    return stream.map(mapper).groupByKey().reduce(reducer);
}
```

You can then call it like so:

```
mapGroupReduce(yourStream,
    (key, value) -> new KeyValue(k, v)),
    (acc, value) -> acc);
```

In your case, instead of using `BiFunction`s, you need to use:

- `KeyValueMapper<K, V, KeyValue<T, U>>` for the mapper
- `Reducer<U>` for the reducer.

However, is this really all that much better than just writing `stream.map(M).groupByKey().reduce(R)` every time? The more verbose version is more explicit, and given the relative sizes of the mapper and reducer, you are not really saving on all that much.

Comment: Thanks, it's a fair point, I might just see if I can extract some pattern from the reduce code instead and keep the main chain as is.

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek Yes, you could write a function that, given some values or even some simpler functions, return a new function to be used in the mapper or reducer. Just remember that it is more important for your code to be easily understandable by another developer than for it to be "beautifully" abstracted.

Comment: I accepted since I'll refrain from overengineering this. But for the record, I did still get a compile error on the code you have here:

`map
(org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KeyValueMapper<? super K,? super V,? extends org.apache.kafka.streams.KeyValue<? extends KR,? extends VR>>)
in KStream cannot be applied
to
(java.util.function.BiFunction<K,V,T>)
 
 reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) KR, VR exist so that BiFunction<K, V, T> conforms to KeyValueMapper<? super K, ? super V, ? extends KeyValue<? extends KR, ? extends VR>>`

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek My answer is written for the very general case, as I could not easily test it with Kafka, but in your code you would replace the `BiFunction`s with a `KeyValueMapper` and a `Reducer` from the Kafka library. I will update my answer with this.